# oracle sql multiple condition for a column

Tags: mysql, oracle

I'm having real trouble here with oracle sql queries, I'm new to this so thanks in advance.

I'm joining two queries with multiple columns, I have 3 conditions for column **DUE_DATE_STATUS** I just don't know how to have 3 conditions in the *Select Statments*

For example

```
SELECT t1, t2, t3, 

FROM B2

UNION

SELECT t1, t2, t3, 

FROM B2
```

and I have this column I want to add, that tells if each row is **late, ontime or null..**

```
SELECT 'LATE_SUBMITTAL' as DUE_DATE_STATUS

from C2 

WHERE 

END_DATE <= START_DATE
```

How do I add all three conditions to the `DUE_DATE_STATUS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a guess, you might be wanting to use a CASE expression.

```
 SELECT t1
      , t2
      , t3
      , CASE WHEN end_date <= start_date THEN 'LATE'
             WHEN end_date >  start_date THEN 'ONTIME'
             ELSE NULL
        END AS due_date_status 
   FROM B2
```

This is just a guess. From the question, it's not clear what we are trying to achieve... an example of the result we want to return.

And we don't know what's up with the table named `C2` in the second query, when the first table references a table named `B2`. I feel like we're missing a whole lot of information about the problem we are trying to solve.

Comment: Yes! that was exaclty what i was looking for , thanks that worked

Comment: Maybe you can help with another i issue im having , I need to enter a flag either Y/N if a Report existed last year . all i have is    CASE WHEN Report _Date = 31/DEC/15  which im pretty sure is laughable to experienced SQL developers, But i have to do it or every year.

Comment: And also the FORM_STATUS EQUALS TO 'Completed'